# Performance issues with ASP.NET 2.0 Routing with IIS6 and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, forms-authentication, url-routing

My aim, for SEO purposes, was to support URLs that provided better indexing and closer matches to the keyword that are important to our website. I therefore made changes to one of my public facing ASP.NET 2.0 pages so that it uses Routing. All this all well documented and easy to implement, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx
http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/

This all works fine on my development environment which uses II7 but our production environment uses II6, so I ended up having to uses "wildcard application mapping". This is really easy to set up (see the pervious links for details).

However, whenever I try and select a routed link it take >40 seconds to return a page; everything else work fine as before. I knew we'd experience some performance issues with IIS6 "wildcard mapping" support but this is definitely not right.

My theory is that this is somehow down to forms authentication and am wondering if anyone has seen this type of behaviour before and/or can suggest potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried routing with IIS6, I set a key in web.config for IIS version and check that in my global.asax and register the route only for IIS7. In the production I change key to 6 and keep it to 7 on dev.

```
    <add key="iisVersion" value="6"/>
```

Note: i dont use routing in IIS6, for SEO purposes I use 301 redirects in IIS6 for friendly url.

Are you planning to migrate iis6 to 7 in production? Hope this helps..

Comment: Our production environment will be II6 for at least another 6 months, so really have to find a routing/ rewriting solution for IIS6.  I'll check out 301 redirects to see if that's a workable alternative.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using url rewrite? http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/